# LLVM - fastest way to count how many bits of an integer are on

Tags: llvm

I have a register `%v1` with type `i256`.

I want to know how many bits are equal to 1.

For example, if `%v1` equals `110....001`, I want the result to be `3`.

Is there a quick way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLVM has an intrinsic for this called [ctpop](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-ctpop-intrinsic) (short for count population.)

> **Syntax:**
>
> This is an overloaded intrinsic. You can use llvm.ctpop on any integer
> bit width, or on any vector with integer elements. Not all targets
> support all bit widths or vector types, however.
>
> ```
> declare i8 @llvm.ctpop.i8(i8  <src>)
> declare i16 @llvm.ctpop.i16(i16 <src>)
> declare i32 @llvm.ctpop.i32(i32 <src>)
> declare i64 @llvm.ctpop.i64(i64 <src>)
> declare i256 @llvm.ctpop.i256(i256 <src>)
> declare <2 x i32> @llvm.ctlz.v2i32(<2 x i32> <src>, i1 <is_zero_undef>)
> ```
>
> **Overview:**
>
> The ‘llvm.ctpop’ family of intrinsics counts the number of bits set in a value.
>
> **Arguments:**
>
> The only argument is the value to be counted. The argument may be of any integer type,
> or a vector with integer elements. The return type must match the argument type.
>
> **Semantics:**
>
> The ‘llvm.ctpop’ intrinsic counts the 1’s in a variable, or within each element of a
> vector.

I believe something like the following should work.

```
declare i256 @llvm.ctpop.i256(i256)

%popcount = call i256 @llvm.ctpop.i256(i256 %v1)
```